# Prove: $|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_n|\leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{2}_n}$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

> For all n $\{x_n\}$ are real numbers
>
> Prove: $$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_n\right|\leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x^{2}_n}$$

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_n\right|= \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_n\right)^2}\leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_n^2}$$

Is this all?

Comment: I thinkyou shoud detail the proof of he inequality

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525441/prove-x-1-x-n2-leq-nx-12-x-n2?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you obtained the last inequality in your proof - it would help if you elaboated a bit.

I would just use Cauchy Schwarz:

If $x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and $y=(1/n,1/n,....,1/n)$, then
$$\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_n\right| = |x\cdot y| \le \sqrt{|x\cdot x||y\cdot y|}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^2}$$

Comment: Isnt it 
$\left|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_n\right| = |x\cdot y| \le \sqrt{|x\cdot x||y\cdot y|}=  \sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^2} \leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^2}$?

Comment: Note that if $x=(1/n,1/n,...,1/n)$, then $x\cdot x = 1/n^2+1/n^2+...+1/n^2= n(1/n^2)=1/n$.